I am trying to deploy a token faucet contract using Alchemy API, but I keep getting this error when I hit migrate, and I have checked all details
require('dotenv').config();
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const { createPublicClient, http } = require("viem");
const { lineaSepolia } = require("viem/chains");

const { ALCHEMY_API_KEY, MNEMONIC } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    linea: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, `https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`),
      network_id: 11155111,
      chain_id: 59144,
      gas: 4500000,
      gasPrice: 10000000000
    },
  },

  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.20",
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 200
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

The error:
C:\Users\Admin\tokenfaucet\node_modules\eth-block-tracker\src\polling.js:51
        const newErr = new Error(`PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:\n${err.stack}`)
                       ^
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
undefined
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (C:\Users\Admin\tokenfaucet\node_modules\eth-block-tracker\src\polling.js:51:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
UnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> {
    code: -32603,
    message: 'Unknown Error: {"message":"Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Page Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{},"_links":{}}]},"_links":{"self":{"href":"/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/fndhAgbM6BS0UhuEsItOHgnXE8lWQPDt","templated":false,"profile":null,"deprecation":null,"title":null,"hreflang":null,"type":null,"name":null}}}',
    data: { originalError: {} }
  }
} {
  code: -32603,
  message: 'Unknown Error: {"message":"Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Page Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{},"_links":{}}]},"_links":{"self":{"href":"/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/fndhAgbM6BS0UhuEsItOHgnXE8lWQPDt","templated":false,"profile":null,"deprecation":null,"title":null,"hreflang":null,"type":null,"name":null}}}',
  data: { originalError: {} }
}
Promise {
  <rejected> {
    code: -32603,
    message: 'Unknown Error: {"message":"Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Page Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{},"_links":{}}]},"_links":{"self":{"href":"/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/bKu20QeWAff01sNwBzs1TXxbMs90bkL1","templated":false,"profile":null,"deprecation":null,"title":null,"hreflang":null,"type":null,"name":null}}}',
    data: { originalError: {} }
  }
} {
  code: -32603,
  message: 'Unknown Error: {"message":"Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Page Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{},"_links":{}}]},"_links":{"self":{"href":"/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/fndhAgbM6BS0UhuEsItOHgnXE8lWQPDt","templated":false,"profile":null,"deprecation":null,"title":null,"hreflang":null,"type":null,"name":null}}}',
  data: { originalError: {} }
}
Promise {
  <rejected> {
    code: -32603,
    message: 'Unknown Error: {"message":"Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Page Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{},"_links":{}}]},"_links":{"self":{"href":"/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/fndhAgbM6BS0UhuEsItOHgnXE8lWQPDt","templated":false,"profile":null,"deprecation":null,"title":null,"hreflang":null,"type":null,"name":null}}}',
    data: { originalError: {} }
  }
} {
  code: -32603,
  message: 'Unknown Error: {"message":"Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Page Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{},"_links":{}}]},"_links":{"self":{"href":"/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/fndhAgbM6BS0UhuEsItOHgnXE8lWQPDt","templated":false,"profile":null,"deprecation":null,"title":null,"hreflang":null,"type":null,"name":null}}}',
  data: { originalError: {} }
}
Promise {
  <rejected> {
    code: -32603,
    message: 'Unknown Error: {"message":"Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Page Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{},"_links":{}}]},"_links":{"self":{"href":"/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/fndhAgbM6BS0UhuEsItOHgnXE8lWQPDt","templated":false,"profile":null,"deprecation":null,"title":null,"hreflang":null,"type":null,"name":null}}}',
    data: { originalError: {} }
  }
} {
  code: -32603,
  message: 'Unknown Error: {"message":"Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Page Not Found","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{},"_links":{}}]},"_links":{"self":{"href":"/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/https://linea-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/fndhAgbM6BS0UhuEsItOHgnXE8lWQPDt","templated":false,"profile":null,"deprecation":null,"title":null,"hreflang":null,"type":null,"name":null}}}',
  data: { originalError: {} }
}

